# How to solve following equation with multiple random variables

Tags: equation-solving, probability-or-statistics, programming

How can I program the following problem into Mathematica?

$X,Y$ are i.i.d. Exponentially distributed random variables. Such that $X\sim\exp(1), \ Y\sim\exp(1)$.

All other variables are positive real-valued.

$$\Phi =\mathbb{P}\left[P_v \geq A + \frac{B}{Y}\right] $$

### $$
P_v=
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
 a\left(\frac{b}{1+\exp\left(-\bar \mu\frac{P_s X}{r^\alpha}+\varphi\right)}-1\right), & \text{if}\ \frac{P_s X}{r^\alpha}\geq P_a,\\
0, & \text{otherwise}.
\end{array}
\right.
$$

**My solution**

\begin{multline}
  \Phi = \mathbb{P}\left[ a\left(\frac{b}{1+\exp\left(-\bar \mu\frac{P_s X}{r^\alpha}+\varphi\right)}-1\right) \geq A  +  \frac{B}{Y}\right]\mathbb{P}\left[X \geq \frac{P_ar^\alpha}{P_s}\right] + {\mathbb{P}\left[0 \geq A + \frac{B}{Y}\right] \mathbb{P}\left[X \geq \frac{P_ar^\alpha}{P_s}\right]} 
\end{multline}

Given that $\mathbb{P}[0>A+\frac{B}{Y}] = 0$

$$ \Phi = \mathbb{P}\left[a\left(\frac{b}{1+\exp\left(-\bar \mu\frac{P_s X}{r^\alpha}+\varphi\right)}-1\right) \geq A + \frac{B}{Y}\right] \exp\left(-\frac{P_ar^\alpha}{P_s}\right) $$

Now consider only the first part of the expression on the right side of the equation, and letting $c = \frac{\bar{\mu}P_s}{r^{\alpha}}$.

$$ \mathbb{P}\left[a\left(\frac{b}{1+\exp\left(-\bar \mu\frac{P_s X}{r^\alpha}+\varphi\right)}-1\right) \geq A + \frac{B}{Y}\right] = \mathbb{P}\left[\frac{ab}{1+\exp\left(-c X+\varphi\right)}-a \geq A + \frac{B}{Y}\right]$$

consider $D = A + a$, with mathematical manipulations and using the fact that $\mathbb{E}[Y] = \frac{1}{\lambda} = 1$ and $\mathbb{E}[e^{-sX}] = \frac{1}{1+s}$, we get:

$$ = \mathbb{P} \left[Y \geq \frac{1}{ab}(DY + B). (1+e^\varphi e^{-c X}) \right] = \mathbb{P} \left[ Y\geq \frac{B (1 + e^\varphi e^{-cX})}{(ab - D)(1+e^\varphi e^{-cX})} \right]  $$

$$= \mathbb{P} \left[ Y\geq \mathbb{E}_X\left[\frac{B (1 + e^\varphi e^{-cX})}{ab - D(1+e^\varphi e^{-cX})}\right] \right] \ \ \ (1)$$

**My Code in Mathematica is as follows. But the Analysis does not meet Simulation.**

```
Egx = Expectation[(B * (1 + E^\[CurlyPhi]*E^(-c X)))/(a b - D*(1 + E^\[CurlyPhi]*E^(-c X))), X \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[1]]
    
Probability[Y >= Egx, Y \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[1]]
```

[image: Mathematica solution]

***My question is if my approach towards the solution correct?***

[image: Simulation and Analysis]

Comment: Have a look at [Probability](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Probability.html?q=Probability).

Comment: +1 for your suggestion. Please see the additions that I have performed. Can you please suggest first of all if my approach is correct?

Comment: Simultaneously posted at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/501958/solution-verification-for-an-equation-of-exponentially-distributed-random-variab.

Answer (score 3):

This is just an extended comment for now.

It seems that because $P_v$ and $A+B/Y$ are independent, then determining their respective pdf's and/or cdf's should occur first.

The pdf for $A+B/Y$ is easily found:

```
wDist = 
  TransformedDistribution[A + B/y, y \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[1];
PDF[wDist, w]
```

[image: pdf of A+B/y]

If maybe you're only interested in $B>0$, then there is much simplification.  The point is that the signs of some of the parameters becomes important in getting a final answer.

Determining the distribution of $P_v$ is not so simple as the distribution is a mixture of a discrete distribution with a probability mass at 0 and the remainder being a continuous distribution with

$$\frac{a (b-1) e^{\mu  P_a-\varphi}-a}{e^{\mu  P_a-\varphi}+1}<P_v<a (b-1)$$

My initial attempts at getting a direct symbolic result for the cdf of $P_v$ were not successful.  So I plugged in specific values of the parameters for which *Mathematica* did provide a result.  Looking for patterns I ended up with the following for the cdf of $P_v$:

```
Piecewise[
  {{1, z >= a*(-1 + b)}, 
   {1 - E^(-((Pa*r^α)/Ps)), 
      0 <= z <= (-a + a*(-1 + b)*E^(-φ + Pa*μ))/(1 + E^(-φ + Pa*μ))}, 
   {1 - E^((r^α*(-φ + 2*ArcTanh[(-2 + b)/b - (2*z)/(a*b)]))/(Ps*μ)), 
     (-a + a*(-1 + b)*E^(-φ + Pa*μ))/(1 + E^(-φ + Pa*μ)) < z < a*(-1 + b)}}, 0]
```

[image: CDF for Pv]

From those distributions one might be able to get a symbolic result for $\Phi$.

**Update:**  Still no luck with a completely symbolic solution (and I'm not convinced that a symbolic solution exists but I've been wrong before).  Here is a numerical solution that matches with random sampling:

```
cdf[z_, a_, b_, μ_, Pa_, Ps_, r_, α_, φ_] := 
 Piecewise[{{1, z >= a*(-1 + b)},
   {1 - E^((r^α*(Pa*μ - φ))/(Ps*μ))*(-1 + (a*b)/(a + z))^(r^α/(Ps*μ)), 
    a*(-1 + b/(1 + E^(-(Pa*μ) + φ))) < z < a*(-1 + b)}},
   0]

pdf[w_, A_, B_] := Piecewise[{{B/(E^(B/(-A + w))*(-A + w)^2), w > A}}, 0]

(* Numerical integration *)
prob[a_, b_, μ_, Pa_, Ps_, r_, α_, φ_, A_, B_] :=
  Module[{p},
  p = Exp[-((Pa r^α)/Ps)] - Exp[-((Pa r^α)/Ps)] If[A <= a (b/(1 + Exp[φ - Pa μ]) - 1),
  NIntegrate[cdf[w, a, b, μ, Pa, Ps, r, α, φ] pdf[w, A, B], {w, a (b/(1 + Exp[φ - Pa μ]) - 1), 
  a (b - 1)}] + 1 - E^(B/(A - a (-1 + b))),
  If[A <= a (b - 1), NIntegrate[cdf[w, a, b, μ, Pa, Ps, r, α, φ] pdf[w, A, B], 
  {w, A, a (b - 1)}] + 1 - E^(B/(A - a (-1 + b))), 1]];
  p]

(* Random sampling *)
sample[a_, b_, μ_, Pa_, Ps_, r_, α_, φ_, A_, B_] := Module[{n, x, Pv, w, Pv2},
  n = 1000000;
  x = RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[1], n];
  Pv = If[# >= r^α Pa/Ps, a (b/(1 + Exp[-(μ Ps/r^α) # + φ]) - 1), 0] & /@ x;
  w = A + B/RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[1], n];
  Length[Select[Pv - w, # >= 0 &]]/n // N
  ]
```

Now with an example:

```
prob[4, 6, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3]
(* 0.105301 *)
SeedRandom[12345];
sample[4, 6, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3]
(* 0.104986 *)
```

I'll add more explanation later.

Comment: First of all, I HIGHLY appreciate the work you put in for the problem that was not yours. I really do. I am trying the understand your solution and will see how the results match with my simulation. Even if it does not match, I appreciate you took time out.

Comment: One thing, how should I interpret the last case of the final output? I think I have seen this type of case only in Mathematica, but I don't know what does it means that Out is 0 when the case is True.

Comment: I take the "True" to mean a condition that isn't satisfied by any of the above conditions.  So in this case the cdf is zero whenever $z\leq \frac{a (b-1) e^{\mu  \text{Pa}-\varphi }-a}{e^{\mu  \text{Pa}-\varphi }+1}$.  (I'll clean up the notation sometime after Christmas.  The $z$ should really be $P_v$.)

Comment: Are there any restrictions on the parameters $a$, $b$, $A$, $B$, $\varphi$, $P_a$, $P_s$, $\mu$, $r$, and $\alpha$?  I'm guessing that $a \geq 0$, $B>0$, $\bar{\mu}P_s/r^\alpha>0$, and $P_a r^\alpha /P_s>0$.

Comment: Dear @JimB, all parameters are positive real numbers. Specifically, $a>0$, $b\geq 1$, $A,B,\varphi, P_a, P_s, \mu, r, \alpha$ are all greater than 0