# Expectation with conditional random variable

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions, conditional

Given an Exponentially Distributed Random Variable $X\sim \exp(1)$, I need to find $\mathbb{E}[P_v]$ in Mathematica, where $P_v$ is given as:

[image]

```
F1 = Po/E^(-μ Pth + φ)*((+ E^(-μ Pth + φ))/(+ E^(-μ Ps X r^(-α)  φ)) - 1);

F2 = E^(-X);

F = F1*F2;

Q = (Pth r^α)/Ps;    

Final = Integrate[F, {Y, Q, ∞}]
```

[image: Try in Mathematica]

Comment: I don't understand why the question is closed when so much details are given already. The next thing could be that I would have taken picture of handwritten notes and pasted in the question. At least before closing some would have helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$P_v$ is a mixture of a continuous random variable and a discrete random variable (with a probability mass at 0).  *Mathematica*'s `MixtureDistribution` requires random variables in the mixture distribution to be all discrete or all continuous (and of the same dimension).  The point is that the determination of distributions and associated summaries usually can't be fully developed with single functions.

For $P_v$, there is a probability mass at zero with probability $1-e^{-\frac{\text{Pa} r^{\alpha }}{\text{Ps}}}$:

```
Probability[x < r^α Pa/Ps, x \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[1]]
```

[image: Probability of P_v=0]

The cdf of the random variable $P_v | X\geq r^\alpha P_a/P_s$ is given in this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/237037/how-to-solve-following-equation-with-multiple-random-variables/):

```
cdf[z_, a_, b_, μ_, Pa_, Ps_, r_, α_, φ_] := 
  Piecewise[{{1, z >= a*(-1 + b)}, 
  {1 - E^((r^α*(Pa*μ - φ))/(Ps*μ))*(-1 + (a*b)/(a + z))^(r^α/(Ps*μ)), 
    a*(-1 + b/(1 + E^(-(Pa*μ) + φ))) < z < a*(-1 + b)}},
   0]
```

Therefore, the pdf is found with the following:

```
D[cdf[z, a, b, μ, Pa, Ps, r, α, φ], z]
```

[image: pdf of Pv given X > r^alpha Pa/Ps]

The mean of  $P_v | X\geq r^\alpha P_a/P_s$  is

```
Integrate[
 z (a b E^((r^α (Pa μ - φ))/(Ps μ)) r^α (-1 + (a b)/(a + z))^(-1 + r^α/(Ps μ)))/
  (Ps (a + z)^2 μ), {z, (-a + a b - a E^(-Pa μ + φ))/(1 + E^(-Pa μ + φ)), a (b - 1)}, 
 Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 1, r > 0, α > 0, Pa > 0, Ps > 0, μ > 0, φ > 0}]
```

[image: Mean of Pv given X >= r^alpha Pa/Ps]

So the unconditional mean of $P_v$ can be written as a weighted mean of the two random variables:

```
mean[a_, b_, μ_, Pa_, Ps_, r_, α_, φ_] := (1 - E^(-((Pa r^α)/Ps)))*0 + 
  E^(-((Pa r^α)/Ps))*a (-1 + b Hypergeometric2F1[1, r^α/(Ps μ), 1 + r^α/(Ps μ), -E^(-Pa μ + φ)])
```

[image: Unconditional mean of Pv]

Does this match up with the results from random sampling?

```
sample[a_, b_, μ_, Pa_, Ps_, r_, α_, φ_] := 
 Module[{n, Pv, x},
  n = 1000000;
  x = RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[1], n];
  Pv = If[# >= r^α Pa/Ps, a (b/(1 + Exp[-(μ Ps/r^α) # + φ]) - 1), 0] & /@ x;
  Mean[Pv]]

mean[3, 4, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3] // N
(* 1.64244 *)
SeedRandom[12345];
sample[3, 4, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 3]
(* 1.64157 *)
```

Comment: I highly appreciate the effort and personal time you have put into this. I will compare the results with my simulation after getting free from the module exam I'll have to take this week. But much appreciate your input at this moment.

Comment: Glad I could help.  You asked an interesting question (at least for me).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you change notation and produce what seems to be a more complicated than necessary version of $g(x)$.  If you just add assumptions to the integration, then you'll get an answer with your original code.  I would think that defining $g(x)$ as

```
g[x_]:= a (b/(1 + Exp[-μ Ps x/r^α + ϕ]) - 1)
```

would be more straightforward.  Here you're using [the law of the unconscious statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) to find the mean:

```
Integrate[g[x] Exp[-x], {x, Pa r^α/Ps, ∞}, 
  Assumptions -> {Ps > 0, Pa > 0, a > 0, b > 0, μ > 0, ϕ > 0, Ps > 0, r > 0, α > 0}] // FullSimplify
```

[image: Integration result]

This gives the same numerical results as my other answer.